# How to reduce weird polygon artifacts?

Tags: opengl, graphics, antialiasing

I wrote an application that takes an obj file, parses all the vertices, UV coordinates and normals, loads them into an OpenGL VBO and presents the model on screen. It works, but I'm getting annoying aliasing artifacts.

**Notice black edges popping in and out of existence:**

[image]

This happens with every model I load. I have tried enabling antialiasing, but although edges appear less jagged, the black artifacts still appear, only smoother. I need them completely removed.

What's the best way to fix this?

Comment: Oh wow it failed to initialize OpenGL, that's a serious bug...I'll try to fix that after a good night's sleep (it's 1:37 am here).

Comment: I literally just left the house. I won't be able to test it until tomorrow around noon. I'm also going to delete some of my comments to avoid the appearance of an extended discussion.

Comment: Alright, sorry about the wait. The problem cannot be replicated on my end.  The model looks great, except for the fact that it's missing a triangle in the bed of the truck. I encountered no jittering/black marks at all, the anti-aliasing even looks good on my end.

Comment: I'm guessing it's an Intel driver issue then, thanks for your help. :)